# OpenGL ES 1.x vs. 2.x: OpenGL ES 1.x still worth learning?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to learn OpenGL ES 2.0 on Android.  I run through a few books and web tutorials on the subject.  However, I've noticed that most websites and books focus on OpenGL ES 1.x versions.  If they do teach both, version 1.x is often the main focus while version 2.x is kind of just glanced over.  I assume it's because version 1.x has simply been out longer.

From what I can gather, the main difference is that OpenGL ES 1.x is easier to learn but not as flexible.

Is OpenGL ES 1.x still worth learning?  Is there a reason to use it over OpenGL ES 2.x, or is it pretty much dead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is OpenGL ES 1.x still worth learning?

Yes.

> Is there a reason to use it over OpenGL ES 2.x, or is it pretty much dead?

Almost every Android phone supports OpenGL ES 1.x. However, Android NDK 2.0 (and higher) and Android SDK 2.2 (and higher) supports OpenGL ES 2.x. The version you target depends on your requirements. If you want to target earlier versions of Android OS (such as 1.5, 1.6) you will need to use OpenGL ES 1.x in order to support these devices, and that is one of the reasons why you should learn OpenGL ES 1.x.

Comment: In that case, is there a reason to use OpenGL ES 2.x over 1.x for simple applications?  If I can achieve my render with 1.x, is there a reason to implement both in case the phone does support 2.x? (faster?  Less memory? etc.)

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. If the phone supports OpenGL ES 2.x and you're running OpenGL ES 1.x code on it, the OpenGL ES 1.x will run in a sort of "emulator mode" if the phone supports OpenGL ES 2.x.

Comment: One caveat. Android emulator does 1.x just fine, but not 2.0.